# ubuntu/studio 14.04 Brother Printer error

Tags: printing, brother

In Ubuntu 14.04 as well as in Studio, I'm not able to install my printer anymore. I have a Brother 2250 dn and the normal installation process is crashing.

How should I install the given drivers from the Brother site, once the lib and Cups from the software center/synaptics wouldn't work?

Comment: What is the 'normal installation process'? Can you give more details on this and indicate the exact point at which it's crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this manual http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1854483&page=2&p=11817878#post11817878

It is not man for Brother 2250 dn but should help.